# Multiple If Statements - Checking Player Collision Only Once

Tags: java, if-statement

I am currently making a game and for player movement, I have if statements that check if you are running into the walls.

Here is a small example of what I am doing:

```
if(!(player.intersects(wall1)){

        // move

}
```

However, my problem is that now that I am adding more walls for different levels, the if statements are getting a bit wonky. For example, adding a second wall:

```
    if(!(player.intersects(wall1)){

            // move

    }
    if(!(player.intersects(wall2)){

            // move

    }
```

But this just doubles the movement speed since both result in true if you aren't hitting any walls.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried adding else to it, like this:

```
if(!(player.intersects(wall1)){

        // move

} else
if(!(player.intersects(wall2)){

        // move

}
```

But this will result in not checking for both walls.

How can I accomplish adding multiple if-statements that check for multiple walls effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is check it if hits any of the walls and if not, move

```
if(!(player.intersects(wall1) && !(player.intersects(wall2) /* and so on */){

        // move

}
```

Comment: Aaaaand it was as easy as that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> But this just doubles the movement speed since both result in true if
>   you aren't hitting any walls.

Given that two if-statements, the result should be like this.

[image: Pic for illustration]

This is some simple probability theory.

When you intersects wall1, it will fall into red

When you intersects wall2, it will fall into green

When you are not moving or any other  case, it will fall into black.

> How can I accomplish adding multiple if-statements that check for
>   multiple walls effectively?

I guess you want to check if the player successfully not collide with wall, it will be rewarded with speed.

You need to change the algorithm.
For example,

```
// a line of area is newly added as a checkpoint
if (player not collide with walls and passed through a line of area) { 
    rewarded 
} else if (player collide with walls and passed through a line of area) {
    not rewarded
} else {
    not rewarded
    // it may be probably not moving or not collide with anything and 
    // not passing through our checkpoint
}
```

hope it helps